# Python list element syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I want to use the syntax

```
a = [3, 6]
for x in a:
    x *= 2
```

so 'a' would be [6, 12]

...but this doesn't seem to work. How should I write the code, as simple as possible, to get the wanted effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

`a = [x * 2 for x in a]`

And for a nested list:

```
a = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]
a = [ [x * 2 for x in x] for x in a]
```

Comment: I don't want to look picky though the extra whitespaces are not needed in the second example. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements If it looks messy we can write something from new line or put some nested operations into separate expression/function.

Comment: For this case (multiply by 2), you may find `x + x` is a little faster than `x * 2`

Comment: @gnibbler Right. On my box I gain around 9% of execute time. But I think this has nothing to do with OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

The following code <del>change</del> creates a new int object and rebinds `x`, and not changes the items of the list.

```
for x in a:
    x *= 2
```

To change the item of the list you should use `a[..] = ..`.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] *= 2
```

You can also use List comprehension as the answer of @Hyperboreus.

To change the value of the nested list, use nested loop.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i]):
        a[i][j] *= 2
```

---

Alternative that use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = x * 2
```

Comment: `enumerate(iterable)` yields an `index, element` tuple. Better than `range(len(iterable))` when you need both the index and the element.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, Thank you for comment. I added that as an alternative.

Comment: "loop control variable" is an odd thing to call it. `x` _is_ the items from the list. If `x` was mutable, the normal thing is for `*=` to mutate in place. However `int` is immutable so it just creates a new `int` object and rebinds instead.

Comment: @gnibbler, Thank you for comment. I fixed it. BTW, I saw the `loop control variable` [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function.

```
my_list = [3, 6]
my_list = [x * 2 for x in my_list]

my_list = [3, 6]
my_list = map(lambda x: x * 2, my_list)
```

Comment: Which works only in python2.x and OP asked explicitly about 2 and 3.

Comment: OK in Python 3 for the `map()` case we can do `list(map(func, seq))`. This is just an idea of different ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you find you need to do a lot of these things, maybe you should use numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([3, 6])
>>> a *= 2
>>> a
array([ 6, 12])
```

2 (or more) dimensional array works the same

```
>>> a = np.array([[3, 6],[4,5]])
>>> a *= 2
>>> a
array([[ 6, 12],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

But there is an overhead converting between `list` and `numpy.array`, so it's only worthwhile (efficiency wise) if you need to do multiple operations.

Comment: Oh, great! This will be very useful. Thank you!